# Typescript generics with conditional types

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I have a type containing some conditionals (Note this isn't my actual code, but a stripped down version which tries to highlight the issue with the least amount of code)

```
type A<T> = {
  prop: T;
  value:
    T extends string ? { a: T, b: T } :
    T extends number ? { y: T, z: T } :
    never
}
```

Instantiating variables with this type works fine.  E.g.

```
// works
const a_string: A<string> = {
  prop: '',
  value: { a: '', b: ''}
}

// works
const a_number: A<number> = {
  prop: 0,
  value: { y: 1, z: 1}
}

// errors (as expected)
const a_mistake: A<number> = {
  prop: 0,
  value: { a: '', b: '' } <-- Should be { y:number, z: number }
}
```

My problem lies when I try and create this function:

```
function myFunc<T extends string>(prop: T): A<T> {
  return {
    prop,
    value: { a: prop, b: prop }
  }
}
```

I cannot understand why this does not work.  Typescript complains that what I am returning is not assignable to A:

```
Type '{ a: T; b: T; }' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? { a: T; b: T; } : T extends number ? { y: T; z: T; } : never'.ts(2322)
union.ts(33, 3): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'A<T>'
```

For the life of me I cannot understand why?

Comment: Since your `T` extends string why don't you just use `A<string>` as a return type? Treat `A<T>` as a type which were not evaluated, it just conditional type. And conditoonal type itself can't be assignable to `value`

Comment: The example doesn't cover all the actual cases my code covers.  I have complex objects being passed around (not just primitives like `string`, `number` etc).  Hardcoding the returned `A` to be `A<Object>` means I lose type information.  e.g., if `T` were `{ some: 'complex', type: 2 }`

Comment: I think it worth creating a dictionary for all your cases instead of conditional typing

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Like I understood `myFUnc` contains a `switch` with different cases, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to why this doesn't work, but for some reason typescript is not able to infer the correct type of value property. A way you can solve this is by using type assertions, since you know that the `prop` extends `string`:

```
function myFunc<T extends string>(prop: T) {
    return {
        prop,
        value: { a: prop, b: prop },
    } as A<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overenginered a bit.

All you need to do is to overalod your function.

```js
type A<T> = {
    prop: T;
    value:
    T extends string ? { a: T, b: T } :
    T extends number ? { y: T, z: T } :
    never
}

function myFunc<Prop extends string | number>(prop: Prop): A<Prop>
function myFunc<Prop extends string | number>(prop: Prop) {
    return {
        prop,
        value: { a: prop, b: prop }
    }
}


const result = myFunc('sdf').value.a // ok
const result2 = myFunc(42).value.y // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN4FgBQV9RgBOA9mAFxQIDcuBUAbgIYA2ArhOXQQlBAB7AIAOwAmAZyjjgRAJbCA5lAD8mKE0oIANFABGmqAF8oXPDz6CREqMLYBbXRCIq1ITToBeB46frCIDE64hri4AGZswgDGwLIkwlB2IABikVFwAAqkYBZCYpLScopQAD429o5ESAAUxGSUWWQAlJTwjWBI4Wmx8YkpaZnZuVYFMvJKZbYOTjV1FFDtTZjc%20EQQwGxECdhm9PhzWit7zOycahqE2Tr6l2RGRyE4j6E4UfHSUGvibCzAaH2paLVADk4lEYWBTQAdCcOFCmFAAPSIqAkADWuDewg%20Xx%20wAATP8koCotUACz46GwiBQkBIlHol64IA)

I assume you have a lot of `switch` cases in this function, otherwise you don't even need a generic parameter.